# XAML Binding on UserControl

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have a user control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.Control.MultiSelect">

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <ContentView Padding="10">
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>  

</StackLayout>
```

In the code behind I have

```
public partial class MultiSelect : StackLayout
    {
        public MultiSelect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ListSourceProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create<MultiSelect, ObservableCollection<ListItem>>(p => p.ListSource, new ObservableCollection<ListItem>());

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListSource
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<ListItem>)GetValue(ListSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListSourceProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

In my XAML page I then have

```
<control:MultiSelect x:Name="MyMultiSelect" />
```

> The question is, how do I bind something in the BindingContext of the XAML
>   page to the user control.

In the code behind of the XAML page I have

```
 MyMultiSelect.ListSource = BindingContext.MyList;
```

and this works well. However I don't want anything in the code behind of my XAML page as it goes against the nice clean MVVM pattern I have going on, where my code behind is otherwise nice, clean and empty.

In XAML I have tried

and quite a few other variants but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Did you see [this link](https://jfarrell.net/2015/07/03/data-binding-custom-controls-in-forms/) that describe about data binding in custom controls in Xamarin forms?

Comment: I figured it out. About 2 years later I created my own blog post: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ListSourceProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create<MultiSelect, ObservableCollection<ListItem>>(p => p.ListSource, new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(), BindingMode.Default, null, (bindable, oldVal,newVal)=>{ (bindable as MultiSelect).LisstSource = newVal;});
```